# RAML multiple schemas in one body response

Tags: json, schema, raml

so I have the following raml definition.

```
responses:
  200:
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: !include responseHeader.json
```

Now I need to add another schema that contains this standardHeader, but adds more information.

So the goal would be something like the following:

```
responses:
  200:
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: !include responseHeader.json
        schema: !include responseBody.json
```

It does not seem to work as I always get a "line break" error.
Anyone knows how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify one schema by media type (application/json in your case). 
Headers are specified separately, e.g.:

```
responses:
  200:
    headers:
      UserID:
        type: string
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: !include responseBody.json
```